# Coordinate conversion using Python and filename

Tags: python, coordinate-system, convert, pyproj

I'm trying to create a Python function to recognise which coordinate conversion to execute based on the last part of the filename - either `BNG` for British National Grid or ```IG`` for Irish Grid.

The uploaded file is in CSV format and the filename is extracted and broken up using:

```
                base_filename = os.path.basename(key)
                filename, extension = os.path.splitext(base_filename)
                device_parts = filename.split("_")
                self.device_name = device_parts[1]
                self.device_type = device_parts[2]
```

The filename used is always either `test_data_BNG` or `test_data_IG`

In order to convert the coordinates, I have tried the following code:

```
                if self.device_type == 'BNG':
                    inProj = Proj(init='epsg:27700') # British National Grid
                    outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # WGS84
                    x1, y1 = row[1], row[2]  # easting, northing
                    x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
                    row[1], row[2] = y2, x2
                else:
                    inProj = Proj(init='epsg:29903') # Irish Grid
                    outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # WGS84
                    x1, y1 = row[1], row[2]  # easting, northing
                    x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
                    row[1], row[2] = y2, x2
                
                        
                    json_doc = {}
```

But I get an "`input must be an array, list, tuple or scalar`" error.

How can I get python to convert to the correct coordinate system based on the end of the filename?

Comment: Did you try with `Proj('epsg:4326')`?

Comment: @ThomasG77 yes I tried this too, but then got the error ```b'projection not named'```

Comment: Doing first `import pyproj`. Output of `pyproj.__proj_version__` (version of proj)? Output of `pyproj.__version__` (version of pyproj)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!
The code was reading the column names `easting` and `northing`, which is why it was throwing me the error. Instead I had to skip over the first line by using

```
   line_count += 1
else:
   if self.device_type == 'BNG':
```

Comment: Congrats. Never easy to be stuck but so much happy when found "the" solution ;)